# Problem with str in service client

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a service and this is the message :

```
std_msgs/String pose
---
sensor_msgs/JointState finalpos
```

This is the client :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy 
from interbotix_moveit.srv import pickitstr,pickitstringResponse
from std_msgs.msg import String
rospy.init_node('service_arm_client')
word=String()
rospy.wait_for_service('/widowxl/arm_service')

pose = rospy.ServiceProxy('/widowxl/arm_service',pickitstr)
word = pickitstringResponse()
word= 'Upright'
finalpose = pose(word)
print(finalpose.finalpose)
```

And I get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/michael/catkin_ws/src/interbotix_ros/interbotix_moveit/src/service_client_test.py",
> line 13, in 
> finalpose = pose(word)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py",
> line 435, in **call**
> return self.call(*args, **kwds)   File
> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py",
> line 512, in call
> transport.send_message(request, self.seq)   File
> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py",
> line 665, in send_message
> serialize_message(self.write_buff, seq, msg)   File
> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py",
> line 152, in serialize_message
> msg.serialize(b)   File "/home/michael/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/interbotix_moveit/srv/_pickitstr.py",
> line 58, in serialize
> _x = self.pose.data AttributeError: 'str' object has no
> attribute 'data'

What Is the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345082/problem-with-str-in-service-client/) by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well in your case `pose` is a server proxy, not an actual pose or a string pose request as defined in your srv. Also you are not creating your srv request for the call properly. Check the documentation for the [std_msg/Sring](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html).

You can try the following:

```
word=String()
word.data= 'Upright'
srv_proxy = rospy.ServiceProxy(step.context.set_navigation_config_service_name, String)
response = srv_proxy(word)
```

The response should be of type [sensor_msgs/JointState](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) and you should be able to access its data with `response.specific_field` (for example `response.name[0]` to get the name of the first joint).

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0